# Draw and arrange components on pcb to print and diy

Tags: pcb-design

I search for a program, to linux, which I can draw components on pcb to build later pcb, through [see this link](https://www.google.pt/search?q=copper%20chloride%20printed%20pcb&client=ubuntu&hs=Y6R&channel=fs&biw=1440&bih=780&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwimqtfvm9XQAhXGOhQKHT5iC6cQ_AUIBigB#imgrc=US60jYMLFpRxPM%3A)

I am trying the gEDA schematic editor and Fritzing. But on both programs I can't find cmos 4011 or 4012. Only I can found this cmos: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdwl8.jpg

But, according datasheet this isn't cmos 4011!

Comment: You can probably design your own symbols. If you restrict yourself to only the components available from the stock schematic editor, you won't go very far, I'm afraid.

Comment: @dim hooo, this is my first time with this type software. That is why I am a little lost! I am trying find the option to edit the components according libary

Answer (score 1):

Fritzing is really not meant for anything than breadboards. Drop it.

gEDA is a "vintage" thing. In the open source community, it has been replaced by Kicad.

Your cmos thingies come in a lot of shapes (DIP, PDIP, SOIC,…) – you need to find the right version of the package you want to use, and use that package as footprint, no matter what software you use.

Most editors will come with a library that contains these footprints. You might or might not need to design a schematic symbol yourself that matches that footprint to your specific pin "names" in the schematic.

Comment: Agreed. Fritzing is a toy, and a crappy one at that. Don't use it for anything serious. Get Eagle or KiCAD.

Comment: I "grew up" with Eagle – but right now, if someone isn't already "molded" by any specific tool, I'd recommend getting used to KiCAD. Not only is it both Free as in Beer and as in Speech, it's also free when you end up designing large or layer-heavy PCBs, and, to be frank, it does a few things conceptually better than Eagle, though it certainly hasn't quite reached Eagle's maturity.